# Unable to completely purge fglrx

Tags: 14.04, drivers, amd-graphics, fglrx, software-uninstall

I've got 14.04 and installed the proprietary AMD Catalyst 14.6 using the **Generate Distribution Specific Driver Package Option** described in the [Installer notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx#Install).

I'd now like to change to the `mesa-vdpau-drivers` but cannot completely purge `fglrx` from my system.

What I've tried so far is what I found in several HowTos that basically comes down to running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

However, in my `dmesg` output I still get these lines showing up:

```
[   58.779902] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   58.779916] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   58.798511] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   58.822853] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 1506 MBytes.
[   58.823307] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 9804 count: 1
[   58.824514] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 1, base 0xf000, size: 0x100
[   58.825520] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   58.825577] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 14.10.2 [May  5 2014] with 1 minors
```

The full `dmesg` output is in [this Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8018973/).

Would be grateful for any help...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem trying to run properly the Radeon Open Source driver after a previous installation of fglrx proprietary driver.

In fact, my need of Radeon Open Source driver was link with this post on xbmc forum: [Linux - Radeon OSS with vdpau (howto)](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=174854).

I removed the `fglrx` driver and install open source one following [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx)

But I still had problems with video tearing on XBMC. (No hardware acceleration and 180% of CPU usage in XBMC)

I carefuly read the version of the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file in [the article I used](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=174854) and the one on my system. I noticed that the difference was:

```
LoadModule: "ati"
Warning, couldn't open module ati
UnloadModule: "ati"
Unloading ati
Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
```

So ATI Driver was not used.. and neither was fglrx

```
LoadModule: "fglrx"
Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
UnloadModule: "fglrx"
Unloading fglrx
Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
```

None of the two drivers "fglrx" (because removed) nor "ATI" was taken into account by Xorg. The reason was probably that "fglrx" was not completely removed and "ATI" Radeon not completely installed.

So I ran the installation again

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

And the magic came!
Now in my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file:

```
[ 37959.945] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 37959.945] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 37959.948] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 37959.948]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 37959.948]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[ 37959.948] (==) AIGLX enabled
[ 37959.948] Loading extension GLX
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[ 37959.948] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[ 37959.948] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 37959.948] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[ 37959.949] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[ 37959.949] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[ 37959.949] (II) Unloading fglrx
[ 37959.949] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 37959.949] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[ 37959.949] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[ 37959.949] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 37959.949]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
[ 37959.949]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 37959.949]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 37959.949] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[ 37959.950] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[ 37959.950] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
```

and on XBMC: no more video tearing and 5% CPU usage: Hardware acceleration is working!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I guess you missed the line in my question where I already had stated I used "sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati" so that didn't help unfortunately.